# Return an empty but tell php it means `return false`

Tags: php, arrays, return

Is it possible to return an array, but also tell php it's supposed to mean false?

Example:

```
if ($res = a_function()) {
    // all good
}
else {
    echo getErrorByNumber($res['err_no']);
}
```

`a_function`:

```
function a_function() {
    // do fancy stuff
    if (xy) return true;
    return array('err_no' => 1);
}
```

I guess its not possible, since php will always take an array for `return true`, right?

Comment: return an empty array..

Comment: It's possible because PHP is not strongly typed ? You can test as input if it's 'true' or 'is_array' as mentionned by Abra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lot's of ways.  Probably the preferred one, compare to `true` with type checking `===`:

```
if(($res = a_function()) === true) {
    // all good
}
else {
    echo getErrorByNumber($res['err_no']);
}
```

A non-empty array will always be true:

```
if($res = a_function() && !is_array($res)) {
    // all good
}
else {
    echo getErrorByNumber($res['err_no']);
}
```

Or flip it around:

```
if(is_array($res)) {    //or isset($res['err_no'])
    echo getErrorByNumber($res['err_no']); 
}
else {
    // all good
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem with a byref parameter:

```
function foo(&$errors)
{
  if (allWentWell())
  {
    $errors = null;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    $errors = array('err_no' => 007);
    return false;
  }
}

// call the function
if (foo($errors))
{
}
else
{
  echo getErrorByNumber($errors['err_no']);
}
```

This way you do not have to distinguish between different possible return types and you will not run into type juggling problems. It is also more readable, you know what's inside the $errors variable without documentation. I wrote a small article explaining why [mixed-typed return values](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#mixedReturnType) can be so dangerous.